# How to automatically set formatted value?

Tags: google-visualization

In DataTable document about "formatted value" it said "An example might be assigning the values "low" "medium", and "high" as formatted values to numeric cell values of 1, 2, and 3."
I can use the following lines to do that
        geoData.setValue(0, 1, 1);
        geoData.setFormattedValue(0, 1, 'low');

But is it possible to automatically set formatted value according to the value I set? 
(I see "Formatter" does similar job, but it seems not way to have a customized formmater to convert 1 to 'low', 2 to 'medium', etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use object notation when loading the data.

example, we can add the value `1`

```
data.addRow([1]);
```

or we can use object notation to add the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)...

```
data.addRow([{v: 1, f: 'low'}]);
```

---

**EDIT**

to apply the format once, you would need to use a data view with a calculated column.

see following working snippet,
here, the `format` object is used to map the value to the number,
using a data view...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rank');
  data.addRows([
    [1],
    [1],
    [1],
    [1],
    [1],
    [2],
    [2],
    [2],
    [2],
    [2],
    [2],
    [3],
    [3],
    [3],
    [3],
    [3],
    [3]
  ]);

  var format = {
    1: 'Low',
    2: 'Medium',
    3: 'High'
  };

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var value = dt.getValue(row, 0);
      return {
        v: value,
        f: format[value]
      };
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: data.getColumnType(0)
  }]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  table.draw(view);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: If I have lots of rows with value 1, I need to manually input [{v: 1, f: 'low'}] many times. Is it possible to only input 1 for each row and have formatted value automatically generated? (like what Formatter does)

Comment: see __EDIT__ above, you would have to use a `DataView` to apply the format only once...